# Resizing font in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, fonts

Internet Explorer (at least IE 8) won't resize my text when the following class is used:

```
a {
font: normal 12px Verdana;
}
```

You can see what I mean in the browser under View -> Text Size - Largest

What is the best way to format text so that it is resizable?  I read that **em** can be used, but is there another way without changing the sizes that I've already set?

Comment: `px` is a fixed size and won't be re-sizable in older browsers - `em` and `%` sizes are relative and can grow. However, modern browsers actually "zoom" rather than increase text sizes which is much better for the site.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to make text resizable is to not set font size at all. You should probably consider using a font other than Verdana then, because you probably think it is ugly in typical default font sizes, and this is why you are creating the problem.

If you set font size in pixels, then the logical interpretation, applied by some old browsers, is that you mean what you say – your settings can still be overridden, but not by the usual font size settings available to users.